# Разбить текст по предложениям с сохранением разделителя

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Можно ограничиться тем, что предложение кончается:

"строчная буква" - ". или ! или ?" - "пробел" - "заглавная буква"

**Например:**

"Привет! Я простой текст. Ты сможешь разделить меня?"

['Привет!','Я простой текст.','Ты сможешь разделить меня?']

**Была попытка, но неудачная:**

```
re.split(r'\w[.!?]+\s+[А-Я]', "Hello! I'm John. Are you OK? fine... and so")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делим по пробелу, но используем [позитивный просмотр назад](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BC.D0.BE.D1.82.D1.80_.D0.B2.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.91.D0.B4_.D0.B8_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.B4) чтобы удостоверится, что перед пробелом идет буква и (точка или ! или ?):

```
import re

result = re.split(r'(?<=\w[.!?]) ', "Hello! I'm John. Are you OK? fine... and so")
print (result)

result = re.split(r'(?<=\w[.!?]) ', "Привет! Я простой текст. Ты сможешь разделить меня?")
print (result)
```

Результат:

```
 ['Hello!', "I'm John.", 'Are you OK?', 'fine... and so']
 ['Привет!', 'Я простой текст.', 'Ты сможешь разделить меня?']
```

**P.S.** На Юникоде не проверял. Тестировал на https://repl.it/languages/python3

**UPD** `\w` возможно стоит заменить на перечисление допустимых символов, так как это могут быть буквы, цифры и **знак подчеркивания**.

Comment: Работает, но уже ради интереса, можно ли как-нибудь разбивать не теряя символ (тут пропадает пробел) ?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКузьмин, не хочет питон разбивать по пустому шаблону (не захватывая хотя бы 1 символ), возвращает `ValueError: split() requires a non-empty pattern match.`

Answer (score 1):

```
(.+?[.!?]) - разбивает по  . ! ?
```

Comment: `re.split(r'(.+?[.!?])', 'dfg! Dgfg? ddf. Dfdg. fdgdfg')`<br/>

возвращает вместе с пустыми элементами:
['', 'dfg!', '', ' Dgfg?', '', ' ddf.', '', ' Dfdg.', ' fdgdfg']